# sql query for category heirarchy validations

Tags: sql-server, query, hierarchy

I need to add validation on category creation.

**CASE 1:** `parentId` should be valid if supplied

**CASE 2:** `name` of sibling could not be duplicated

I have this table: **(categories)**

```
    id  | parentId  | name  
   -----|-----------|------
    1   | NULL      | CatA
    2   | 1         | CatA.1
```

(Note: My parent child hierarchy can go up-to nth level)

Now in the above scenario what should not be allowed is:

1. I cannot provide an invalid parentId
2. I cannot create a category with name: CatA where parentId = null
3. I cannot create a category where name: CatA.1 where parentId = 1

Now I am in a nodejs so I need to return these 2 validations errors:

1. The provided parentId is invalid
2. Duplicate name detected

Now I want to achieve this using a single optimized SQL query.
I can use if else statements later on the base of query response.
But for me it is really important that I use single query and that query should be as opptimized as possible.

What I tried so far is:

```
SELECT
    TOP 1 parentId,
    name,
    (
        CASE
            WHEN name = 'CatA.2' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
    ) sortOrder
FROM
    catagories
WHERE
    parentId = 1
ORDER BY
    sortOrder 
DESC
```

Now the issue with  my query is that it doesn't cover all the scenarios.

Can anyone help me with the query?

Comment: check this out: 
[help me write this query in sql.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

Constraints should be embedded in the table definition if possible, eg

```
create table Categories
(
  Id int primary key,
  ParentId int null references Categories,
  Name varchar(20) not null,
  constraint uk_Name_Sibling unique (ParentId,Name)
)
```

Comment: I cannot change the table structure, plus name cannot be unique for other categories, it s only unique on siblings level

Comment: See updated answer